# Why sizeof(Point) is 8?

Tags: c#, .net, sizeof

i wrote code and get strange result- integer i is 8:

```
unsafe
        {
            int i = sizeof(Point);
        }
```

After checking struct Point i found this fields:

```
    public bool IsEmpty { get; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
```

bits math: 32+32+1 = 65 bits, so is > 8 bytes

So, why sizeof returns 8 , but not 9?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`IsEmpty` is a *property*, not a field. Properties are just methods behind the scenes, so they're not part of the size of a structure.

Comment: Yes, you write!

i tried do:

    struct SomeVal
    {
        public Int32 x;
        public Int32 y;
        public bool z;
    }

and is size 12! the smallest block for variable is 4 bytes?

Comment: @zzfima No... Try `struct Test { bool Value; }` 1 byte. What you see is extra padding caused by the fact that `SomeVal` must be aligned on 4 byte boundary (because it contains a `Int32`), so its size must be a multiple of 4.

Comment: Note that padding requirements vary by platform and the CLR doesn't have the same rules regarding member order as C and C++ have, sometimes eliding much of the necessary padding.

Comment: Unless someone is pointing me with a gun, I'd never ever consider how the data are internally treated. Of course, there are headache-cases where you can't avoid it. However, in such a cases, I have an important business calling me abroad...

Comment: @Joey But note that for `struct`, the C# compiler emit a `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 1)]` (see http://goo.gl/V6qH4Y) (note that it is the C# compiler that does it... There is no guarantee that other .NET languages do the same)

Answer (score 5):

The [framework implementation](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/CommonUI/System/Drawing/Point@cs/1/Point@cs) of `Point` uses only two attributes:

```
private int x;
private int y;
```

`Empty` is implemented as

```
[Browsable(false)]
public bool IsEmpty { 
    get {
        return x == 0 && y == 0;
    }
}
```

The two `int` fields occupy 8 bytes - and everything is fine.